# ScrolledComposite showing two scrollbars each for vertical & horizontal scroll

Tags: eclipse, scroll, swt, rcp, composite-controls

My current application is a RCP application using eclipse framework. There is a view whose composite is given to a Scrolled Composite and then all the relevant composites are made with the ScrolledComposite as the parent.

```
protected void createContent(Composite parent) 
{
 ScrolledComposite form = new ScrolledForm(parent,SWT.H_SCROLL|SWT.V_SCROLL);
 GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
 form.getBody().setLayout(layout);
 ......................
 .........................
}
```

The issue is that at times there are two vertical and two horizontal scrollbars visible. One is of the main view and the second is for the ScrolledComposite.

I have implemented a ResizeListener that will change the MinSize of the SCrolledLayout dynamically.

```
Rectangle rect = form.getClientArea();
form.setMinSize(SWT.DEFAULT,SWT.DEFAULT);
```

However Still at times there are two Scrollbars visible but they are of no use and they look annoying. So Since the scrollbars are of no use I am disabling them in the ResizeListener itself.

```
Rectangle rect = form.getClientArea();
form.getHorizontalBar().setVisible(false);
form.getVerticalBar().setVisible(false);
form.setMinSize(SWT.DEFAULT,SWT.DEFAULT);
```

Is there a better way to do this or am I goofing up somewhere.

Comment: This is usually because you have another control inside the scrolled composite which also does scrolling. Show us a [mcve]

Comment: The code is quiet huge and me internally use GridData hence the scroll comes for the parent.